# Materialize labels doesnt work when highligted

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

i have a problem with materialize plugin, when the user select the label using mouse, then the label don't go to up, and the user can't enter a text.

[image]

i want to prevent user from selecting the label, the label should directly go to up once the mouse down event triggered inside the textbox.

thanks,

Update:
a part of code :

[image]

Comment: Have you imported `jquery` before `materialize.js`?

Comment: JQuery is imported in the master page.

Comment: I am saying, Have you imported `jquery` before `materialize.js`?

Comment: yes, jquery is imported at the first in master page

Comment: Okay. Can you put your code in post?

Answer (score 0):

Use `class="active"` on the label and make textbox id same as label id.

Example:

```
<input type="text" id="job_title" name="job_title">
<label for="job_title"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is issue with imports. Import `jquery` first and then `materialize.js`, because I have tried importing `materialize.js` first and I get the same issue, and Put `label` tag after `input` tag. **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tirth_Patel/zofrpto0/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-field">
     <input id="ct100_Cph_CaptchaLg_UserName" class="loginClass" name="ct100$Cph$CaptchaLg$UserName" type="text" />
    <label for="ct100_Cph_CaptchaLg_UserName">Email</label>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 .input-field label {
        pointer-events: none;
   }
```

Will do the job, seems like is something related to web forms controls, because if you remove the runat attribute it works as expected.